# SSIS Package not holding SQLBase password

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, parameter-passing, sqlbase

We are trying to create a SQL job to run an SSIS package but it always fails because the password is not propegating to integration services.

It works when the password is entered manually into the XML code and run from BIDS.

We have tried putting the password into the integration services configuration for the package - but it gets removed as soon as save is clicked.

We have also tried putting it in the configuration of the job but with the same result.

The password is to access the SQLBase database - there is no chance of upgrading as it is a 3rd party solution.

Please can anyone advise on a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be the following: In your SSIS solution define a project parameter which contains the COMPLETE Connectionstring including user and password. Then put an expression on your Connectionmanager and Replace the ConnectionString with your newly defined Parameter. This is how I solved this problem in the past.
However, instead of the Project Parameter you could use a regular variable as well, but the project parameter provides the possibility to change it later on e.g. via an environment.